# what does `~` mean in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I view the code of express, and see this code  https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L490

```
if ('all' == envs || ~envs.indexOf(this.settings.env)) fn.call(this);
```

what the `~` means before `envs`

Comment: As indicated in the answers `~` is a bitwise not, so that code is checking whether the return from `indexOf()` is -1. In my opinion this is not a good practice because it is a "trick" that makes the code harder to read and maintain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case you were wondering why it is used in that situation, it is a shorthand for finding out if `indexOf` method found something.

`indexOf` returns -1 when it doesn't find something, and >= 0 when it does. So when you do ~-1 you get 0 (a falsy value) and when you do it on anything else you get a truthy value.

So:

```
if( ~str.indexOf( "something" ) ) {
...
}
```

Is a shorter way of saying

```
if( str.indexOf( "something" ) !== -1 ) {
...
}
```

If you are wondering how is -1 the NOT of 0, then read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: Does the Javascript standard mandate storing numbers in 2's complement form? If not, this isn't really an awesome way of checking if a number equals -1.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Javascript numbers are stored as IEEE754 doubles, but converted to signed 32-bit integers for bitwise operations, and then converted back. I'll find a reference for you. Edit: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf page 72

Comment: @Esailija, as there are no negative indices, one should better use `s.indexOf(...) < 0`, as it is much more easy understandable.

Comment: @kay yes it is more understandable, I am not saying I recommend this practice.

Answer (score 8):

It's the Bitwise NOT operator:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators