# How does !!~ (not not tilde/bang bang tilde) alter the result of a 'contains/included' Array method call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators, bitwise-operators

If you read the comments at the jQuery `inArray` page [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), there's an interesting declaration:

```
!!~jQuery.inArray(elm, arr)
```

Now, I believe a double-exclamation point will convert the result to type `boolean`, with the value of `true`.  What I don't understand is what is the use of the tilde (`~`) operator in all of this?

```
var arr = ["one", "two", "three"];
if (jQuery.inArray("one", arr) > -1) { alert("Found"); }
```

Refactoring the `if` statement:

```
if (!!~jQuery.inArray("one", arr)) { alert("Found"); }
```

Breakdown:

```
jQuery.inArray("one", arr)     // 0
~jQuery.inArray("one", arr)    // -1 (why?)
!~jQuery.inArray("one", arr)   // false
!!~jQuery.inArray("one", arr)  // true
```

I also noticed that if I put the tilde in front, the result is `-2`.

```
~!!~jQuery.inArray("one", arr) // -2
```

I don't understand the purpose of the tilde here.  Can someone please explain it or point me towards a resource?

Comment: Whoever would write code like that needs to step away from the keyboard.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Why? `~jQuery.inArray()` is actually very useful - possibly even a very good reason why the search functions return `-1` for failure (the only value whose two's complement is falsy). Once you've seen and understood the trick, I feel it is even more readable than `!= -1`.

Comment: @Amadan -- no.  Just no.  Seriously, I can't believe you're defending `!!~` for *anything*.

Comment: @KirkWoll: *shrug*. In fact I do think `!!~` is an overkill, since JS deals with truthy/falsy values well enough. But a simple `~` as an alternative to `!= -1` for `indexOf` and `inArray` tests, particularly in conditionals, I'd have absolutely no problems with that.

Comment: Problem is, it's just that: A "trick". The main difference between `if (x != -1)` and `if (~x)` to me, is that the former actually expresses what you intend to do. The latter expresses you wanting to do something else entirely ("please convert my 64-bit Number to a 32-bit integer, and check if bitwise NOT of that integer is truthy"), where you just happen to get the desired result in this one case.

Comment: @TheKaneda: Depends if you think of the `-1` that the search functions return as a coincidence (which makes `~` an ugly exploit), or as a design decision (which makes `~` supremely suited for that particular test). I don't care that `x` is `-1` - it is as arbitrary to me as your "please...". What I care about is whether something is found or not; and given that the search functions have a consistent API returning `-1` for "not found", `~` is a rather clean way to test for it. When you recognise the `$.indexOf(...) != -1` as an idiom and not as a test for equality to `-1`, `~` is as meaningful.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: @20100 - Read the question... the OP has linked to that same question, and stated that he has read it.

Comment: `>= 0` probably wasn't *[leet](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=leet)* enough, so the more cryptic `!!~` was used.

Comment: The regular person way is [faster for me](http://jsperf.com/cryptic-versus-non-cryptic).

Comment: [JavaScript hipsters...](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3057)

Comment: @Yoshi, technically speaking, `foo >= 0` and `!!~foo` return differing results. `foo != -1` and `!!~foo` would be equivalent.

Comment: @minitech test 2 should be !== -1, not > -1

Comment: @octal9: No it shouldn't. `indexOf` will never return `-2` or lower.

Comment: In case you're thinking that `!!~` is (way) faster than `!= -1`: http://jsperf.com/faster-way-to-check-expr-not-equal-to-minus-one

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does `~` mean in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191531/what-does-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: @TheKaneda Yep, but the trick fixes another "trick". [`inArray` unf doesn't express what it intends to do either](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/inarray). `~` is the way to make `inArray` "return" the boolean its name implies it would in the fewest keystrokes.  It's a sort of two wrongs make a right situation, though I'd agree that's not really a justification. [This guy's `isInArray` is a solution](http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2011/01/jquery-is-in-array-boolean-sugar/), as `inArray` can't be changed without breaking existing code. Using ~ *with inArray* makes sense tho in gen a bad idea, perhaps

Comment: see also [What does a tilde do when it precedes an expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12299665/1048572) and [What does `!!~` mean in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10582286/1048572)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The tilde operator isn't actually part of jQuery at all - it's a bitwise NOT operator in JavaScript itself.

See *[The Great Mystery of the Tilde(~)](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/)*.

You are getting strange numbers in your experiments because you are performing a bitwise logical operation on an integer (which, for all I know, may be stored as two's complement or something like that...)

*[Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)* explains how to represent a number in binary. I think I was right.

Comment: Fixed! (Changed it to another link that, bizarrely enough, was written after my original answer...)

Answer (score 125):

There's a specfic reason you'll sometimes see `~` applied in front of `$.inArray`.

Basically,

```
~$.inArray("foo", bar)
```

is a shorter way to do

```
$.inArray("foo", bar) !== -1
```

`$.inArray` returns the index of the item in the array if the first argument is found, and it returns -1 if its not found. This means that if you're looking for a boolean of "is this value in the array?", you can't do a boolean comparison, since -1 is a truthy value, and when $.inArray returns 0 (a falsy value), it means its actually found in the first element of the array.

Applying the `~` bitwise operator causes `-1` to become `0`, and causes 0 to become `-1. Thus, not finding the value in the array and applying the bitwise NOT results in a falsy value (0), and all other values will return non-0 numbers, and will represent a truthy result.

```
if (~$.inArray("foo", ["foo",2,3])) {
    // Will run
}
```

And it'll work as intended.

Comment: How well supported is this in browsers (now in 2014?)  Or was it supported perfectly all along?

Comment: i would be surprised if basic operations like these wouldn't be perfect.

Answer (score 107):

`!!~expr` evaluates to `false` when `expr` is `-1` otherwise `true`.
It is same as `expr != -1`, only broken*

---

It works because [JavaScript bitwise operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) convert the operands to 32-bit signed integers in two's complement format. Thus `!!~-1` is evaluated as follows:

```
   -1 = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111b // two's complement representation of -1
  ~-1 = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000b // ~ is bitwise not (invert all bits)
   !0 = true                                     // ! is logical not (true for falsy)
!true = false                                    // duh
```

A value other than `-1` will have at least one bit set to zero; inverting it will create a truthy value; applying `!` operator twice to a truthy value returns boolean true.

When used with `.indexOf()` and we only want to check if result is `-1` or not:

```
!!~"abc".indexOf("d") // indexOf() returns -1, the expression evaluates to false
!!~"abc".indexOf("a") // indexOf() returns  0, the expression evaluates to true
!!~"abc".indexOf("b") // indexOf() returns  1, the expression evaluates to true
```

---

* `!!~8589934591` evaluates to false so this <del>abomination</del> cannot be reliably used to test for `-1`.

Comment: In a stable library, I see no issue with using `~foo.indexOf(bar)`, it's not significant savings on characters or performance, but it is a relatively common shorthand in the same way that `foo = foo || {}` is.

Comment: It is is not an issue... not at least until someone else is asked to continue with your code.

Comment: @zzzzBov to [expand on Salman's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582286/what-does-mean-in-javascript#comment13710140_10582345) comment: [always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/coding-for-violent-psychopaths.html)

Comment: @ahsteele, I'm well aware of that rule, however bitwise operators are a part of every programming language that I can think of. I try to program in a way that is readable to someone *who can read code*. I don't stop using features of a language simply because someone else doesn't understand it, otherwise I [wouldn't even be able to use `!!`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript).

Comment: Strictly speaking, `>= 0` doesn't have the same behavior as `!!~`. `!== -1` is closer.

Comment: Looks really handy if you read from Access databases, as `false` is encoded as -1 and `true` 0 IIRC.

Comment: Great explanation, and I have to agree with this answer: if you're writing code that you plan to share please don't do this. Your coworkers/contributors will thank you.

Answer (score 35):

`~foo.indexOf(bar)` is a common shorthand to represent `foo.contains(bar)` because the `contains` function doesn't exist.

Typically the cast to boolean is unnecessary due to JavaScript's concept of "falsy" values. In this case it's used to force the output of the function to be `true` or `false`.

Comment: +1 This answer explains the "why" better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 18):

`jQuery.inArray()` returns `-1` for "not found", whose complement (`~`) is `0`. Thus, `~jQuery.inArray()` returns a falsy value (`0`) for "not found", and a truthy value (a negative integer) for "found". `!!` will then formalise the falsy/truthy into real boolean `false`/`true`. So, `!!~jQuery.inArray()` will give `true` for "found" and `false` for "not found".

Answer (score 13):

The `~` for all 4 bytes `int` is equal to this formula `-(N+1)`

**SO**

```
~0   = -(0+1)   // -1
~35  = -(35+1)  // -36 
~-35 = -(-35+1) //34
```

Comment: This isn't always true, since (for example) `~2147483648 != -(2147483648 + 1)`.

Answer (score 11):

Tilde is bitwise NOT - it inverts each bit of the value. As a general rule of thumb, if you use `~` on a number, its sign will be inverted, then 1 will be subtracted.

Thus, when you do `~0`, you get -1 (0 inverted is -0, subtract 1 is -1).

It's essentially an elaborate, super-micro-optimised way of getting a value that's always Boolean.

Answer (score 10):

The `~` operator is the bitwise complement operator. The integer result from `inArray()` is either -1, when the element is not found, or some non-negative integer.  The bitwise complement of -1 (represented in binary as all 1 bits) is zero. The bitwise-complement of any non-negative integer is always non-zero.

Thus, `!!~i` will be `true` when integer "i" is a non-negative integer, and `false` when "i" is exactly -1.

Note that `~` always coerces its operand to integer; that is, it forces non-integer floating point values to integer, as well as non-numeric values.

Answer (score 8):

You're right: This code will return `false` when the `indexOf` call returns -1; otherwise `true`.

As you say, it would be much more sensible to use something like

```
return this.modifiedPaths.indexOf(path) !== -1;
```

Comment: But that's 3 more bytes to send to the client! edit: (just joking by the way, posted my comment and realized it wasn't obvious (which is both sad and silly))

Comment: @Wesley: That's true, but it only has to be sent to each client *once*, assuming the client will cache the `.js`. Having said that, they could use `>=0` rather than `!==-1` - no extra bytes to send and still more readable than the bit-twiddling version.

Comment: Who's trolling who here? ;) I guess I took it for granted that writing readable code is better than cryptic pre-optimized code that generates these kind of questions. Just minify later and write readable, understandable code now.

Comment: Personally I'd say that `> -1` is even more readable, but that's probably very subjective.

Answer (score 6):

The `~` operator is the bitwise NOT operator. What this means is that it takes a number in binary form and turns all zeroes into ones and ones into zeroes.

For instance, the number 0 in binary is `0000000`, while -1 is `11111111`. Likewise, 1 is `00000001` in binary, while -2 is `11111110`.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it is there because it's a few characters shorter (which library authors are always after). It also uses operations that only take a few machine cycles when compiled into the native code (as opposed to the comparison to a number.)

I agree with another answer that it's an overkill but perhaps might make sense in a tight loop (requires performance gain estimation, though, otherwise may turn out to be premature optimization.)

Answer (score 2):

I assume, since it is a bitwise operation, it is the fastest (computationally cheap) way to check whether path appears in modifiedPaths.

Answer (score 1):

As `(~(-1)) === 0`, so:

```
!!(~(-1)) === Boolean(~(-1)) === Boolean(0) === false
```

Comment: This maybe accurate, but is it a useful explanation for the questioner? Not at all. If I didn't understand it to start with, a terse answer like this wouldn't help.

Comment: I think this answer makes sense. If you have a mathematic brain, you can clearly see which parts are changing at each step. Is it the _best_ answer to this question? No. But it is useful, I think so! +1