# Separate by comma (,) and check if any of the values is = "something"

Tags: javascript, string-parsing

How can I somehow split/separate my JavaScript variable by comma (,).
And then check if `value-of-any-of-the-separated-strings = "something"`

For example, my variable has the value `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2212312`, and I want to check if any of the numbers are `= 7` in a IF-Statement.

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, split the string by `","`. Then, use `indexOf` on the split-string array to see if the target string is found (`-1` means it wasn't found in the array). For example:

```
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,2212312";
var split_str = str.split(",");
if (split_str.indexOf("7") !== -1) {
    // Original string contains 7
}
```

---

**References:**

- `String.prototype.split` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
- `Array.prototype.indexOf` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 6):

This is a simple application of [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var yourVar = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2212312';
function isSeven(val) {
    return val === '7';
}
if (yourVar.split(',').some(isSeven)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Another [common way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10584043/497418) this could be written is:

```
if (~yourVar.split(',').indexOf('7')) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Or if `Array.prototype.contains` has been defined:

```
if (yourVar.split(',').contains('7')) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Or if you want to use a regular expression:

```
if (/(?:^|,)7(?:,|$)/.test(yourVar)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

<sub>**Note:** [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`Array.prototype.contains`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399125/497418) all require polyfills to work correctly cross browser.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Split it into an Array, then use indexOf to see if it's there. If it returns -1, it isn't.

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2212312".split(",").indexOf("7")
```

Answer (score 1):

man i hope it will help you.

```
    var yourValues = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2212312';
    var array = yourValues.split(",");
    boolean isValue = false;
    for(i in array)
    {
       if(array[i]=='7')
       {
             isValue=true;
       }
    }


    if(isValue)
        alert("your number is in the string");
    else
        alert("your number is in the string");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2212312";
var num = 7;
var pieces = str.split(",");
var index = pieces.indexOf(num.toString());
```

It can be done with regular expressions too

```
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2212312";
var num = 7;    
var re = new RegExp("(^|,)" + num + "($|,)");
alert(re.test(str));
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rcqeQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) along with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var someString = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2212312';
var splitArray = someString.split(',');
var sevenPosition = splitArray.indexOf('7');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/f4NLY/

Comment: and if there is 207 or 17 in the array it will fail?

Comment: @epascarello then search for `',7,'` instead.

Comment: and what if it is the first or last item. It would fail again.

Comment: @epascarello removed that part of the answer. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.filter`, something like:

```
var values = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2212312'.split(','), find = 7;
if ( values.filter(function(a){return +a === find;}).length ) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you looking for the "contains" function. You can use jQuery for this.

```
if ($.inArray(7, value-of-any-of-the-seperated-strings))
{
   console.log("there is a 7!")
}
```

Comment: Though it should be mentioned if the OP is not already using jQuery there's no need to include such a heavy library for something that's [native to javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).