# Cannot get document.getElementByID to work

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The following function doesn't work for some reason. Can someone see what the problem is?

```
function checkMaxLen(txt, maxLen) {
    var actualLen = txt.value.length;
    var remain = maxLen - actualLen;
    document.getElementById('remainChar').Value = remain;
}
```

---

```
<input type="text" id="remainChar" runat="server" value="500"/>
```

Whenever I try to run the function, I get this error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'Value': object is null or undefined

Comment: Probably a timing issue, `remainChar` doesn't yet exist when you trying to read it. BTW, `Value` should be `value` ; ).

Comment: When is this function being called?

Comment: @Teemu Based on the function's name and the purpose of the function, I'm sure it's being called at the right time. I would bet the `id` is not "remainChar" and is being modified by ASP.NET like it sometimes does. But the point is that it's not finding the element

Comment: when i type into another textbox

Comment: @Ian I agree, since also `txt.value` seems to be defined too. Maybe more code is needed to solve this.

Comment: I provided the correct  answer with a jsFiddle

Comment: @Teemu But that's a perfect reason why it wouldn't be a timing issue. I bet the code is something like `<input type="text" id="whatever" onkeydown="checkMaxLen(this, 10);" />`

Comment: @MiltiadisKokkonidis No you didn't. That's doesn't solve the immediate problem the OP is having. Once that problem is solved, then they would encounter that using `.Value` is incorrect and your solution would fix that.

Comment: @Ian That's what I tried to say, maybe it's this poor english of mine =).

Comment: @Teemu Haha yeah, that's a reading mistake on my part. I didn't see the "I agree" part I guess

Comment: Missed the runat="server" :-)

Comment: <%= remains.ClientId%> is also needed.  Updated my answer

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the insightful comments to this question and its answers and for your upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the ID of the input in your final HTML.  Since you have `runat="server"` ASP.NET is likely adding its typical container prefixes.

Comment: It'll have a container prefix only if it's in a container :)

Comment: Very true - although there's not enough info in the question to know if it's the problem or not.

Comment: But you're right! And I think that is the problem here. If MasterPages is used or is in a repeater or similar, the control will have a modified id. So the **solution** is to use `document.getElementById("<%= remainChar.ClientID %>")` or whatever the syntax is

Comment: This is probably the issue. You may have to use `<%=remainChar.ClientID%>` to get the actual rendered ID of the input.

Comment: Thanks you that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

**Main Problem:** There is no Javascript getElementById issue, but rather a problem with feeding the right id into getElementById (caused because ASP.NET feels free to change the ids of runat="server" elements) (covered by the accepted answer).  This is what caused the error the OP reported:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'Value': object is null or undefined
```

This was because getElementById was given a non-existent id and returned null.

**Another Problem:** The second problem was indeed a Javascript problem, but not related to getElementById either.   Javascript is case sensitive, so trying to set the  value property of a input element's DOM object cannot be done by trying to set But even if the (non-existent) Value property.

**Solution:**

The correct code that solves both problems follows:

```
  function checkMaxLen(txt, maxLen) {
    var actualLen = txt.value.length;
    var remain = maxLen - actualLen;
    document.getElementById('<%= remainChar.ClientId%>').value = remain 
  }
```

Note: Thanks go to Ian for pointing out an important oversight in my original answer.

Comment: When/Where does it ask to change the `<input>` colour?

Comment: @F4r-20 I think they were demonstrating that the property is the problem, and that other properties would normally work. Which is true. But in this case, that's not the underlying problem

Comment: @F4r-20 Please reverse downvote.  The point was that other properties were working fine when I tried the OP's code in jsFiddle.  Ian was right about me missing the runat="server" but that was fixed almost instantly ...  I never got a downvote before and it hurt my feelings :-)

Comment: @MiltiadisKokkonidis I was the downvoter, as you didn't have the stuff you do now. I removed the downvote since you have completed the answer

Comment: @Ian Thanks :-)  I have now also removed the color example as apparently it confused people (thanks for explaining why I had it there in the first place) and addressed the runat="server" issue that I missed at first as I thought the OP had posted pure html, which I copied straight into jsFiddle in order to confirm my suspicion that Value (instead of value) caused a problem.

Answer (score 0):

case sensitive:

```
document.getElementById('remainChar').value
```

Comment: I tried it but im still getting the error Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined

Comment: Why -1? It *is* case sensitive.

Comment: @F4r-20 Because it doesn't solve the problem - it would solve the eventual problem. The problem is that the element isn't found

Comment: @Ian this site is meant to promote learning. Anything that helps contribute towards solving the problem is a viable answer. It's users that become infatuated with "ultimates" or "end alls" that limit the potential of this site.

Comment: I don't think it's a viable answer. It's a viable comment. Just like those of us commenting on the question above already had. If all viable comments were answers, the site would be too crowded for comfort. Hopefully from this experience, you learn what `object is null or undefined` means.

Comment: And thanks for the downvote on my answer for a different question ( http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12747943/separate-by-comma-and-check-if-any-of-the-values-is-something/12747994 ). I highly doubt an (old) question like that was downvoted randomly, at the same time someone else was upset they received a downvote for a non-viable answer.

Comment: @Ian Are you joking me? Flag it and have a mod take a look. What are you 5? And yes, the site is already over saturated but part of the community experience is addressing repetitive answers in a different form. Not all new guys can realize the context is the same.

Comment: Hey, I wasn't complaining, I just thought it was funny and highly coincidental. I really don't care, it was just weird to happen at the same time. I don't mind saturation, but there's a lot of duplication as well. My point was that people who understand the "context" should be understanding enough to remove their answers that aren't relevant/viable. If it's a duplicate, it should be removed. If it's meant for comments, it should be removed. It's that simple

Answer (score 0):

.Value should be .value, script should be executed after  appears in the source or after the DOMReady event has been fired.

also since this is asp.net the id attribute of the  box will not be "remainChar" but transformed into something else.

so you either need to find out what the final id will be or remove the `runat="server"` attribute

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="remainChar" value="500"/>
<script>
    function checkMaxLen(txt, maxLen) {
        var actualLen = txt.value.length;
        var remain = maxLen - actualLen;
        document.getElementById('remainChar').value = remain;
    }
    checkMaxLen({value:""},20);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The function is being called when typing occurs in a different textbox...so the DOM is plenty ready

Comment: you did not specify that in your question

Comment: It's not my question. And it's in the comments. Not saying it's your fault, but this isn't the problem is all