# what does "~" operator do in this script?

Tags: javascript, operators

Hi im deleting an array from specific index, and I came with this script:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var index = 2;
if (~index) arr.splice(index, 1);
```

I google `"what does "~" operator do in this script?"` and I can't find any answer I guess I'm doing an wrong search can anyone could explain me this operator and what's he name for a properly search?

I have an little suspect that is kind of comparing against (!)(undefined) but not sure...

thanks in advance

Comment: Refer to [MDN Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators). It's easier than Googling the actual operator if you don't know the name of it.

Comment: There's always, what it is called again...oh, right! [The specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.8). ;-) Literally the first thing that comes up if you open the spec and search in it for `~`. (Not that trying to search for it in a search engine wasn't a good try, I'm just linking to the spec with a bit of well-intentioned humor...)

Comment: @scrappedcola About the duplicated question, while the questions have similarities NOTHING referred javascript in the question. Since this Bitwise Operator (now I know how call it) is from javascript (EcmaScript) no from jQuery so I think is not duplicate it.

Comment: @Bergi yeap duplicate thanks but I cant found either google or stackoverflow when I searched for it...

Comment: And I'm asking what does in this script as T.J. Crowder explained to me.. thanks

Comment: @nahum: While the question title may be confusing (they often are), [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9316724/) explains it pretty well.

Comment: @nahum: Try http://symbolhound.com/ if you want to search a character (or operator) whose name you don't know

Comment: nahum: The `~` behaves the same irrespective of what expression it precedes. Doesn't matter if it's operating on the value from a variable, or returned from a jQuery method. It's the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what does “~” operator do in this script?

As others have pointed out, it's the [bitwise NOT operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.8). Which is all well and good, but what's it doing in *this* script was the question. :-)

The idea was *probably* to do pretty much what you said: If `index` is a number, do the `splice`. The first thing the `~` operator does to its operand is convert it to a number if it can. If it can't, the result is `NaN` ("not a number"), which is falsey, and so the condition would be false and the `splice` wouldn't happen.

But the conversion doesn't result in `NaN` *nearly* as often as I suspect the author of that code thought. :-)

Some random examples of things that won't do the `splice`:

```
~-1 === 0
```

And some that *will* do the `splice`:

```
~"foo" === -1
~0 === -1
~1 === -2
~2 === -3
~true === -2
~false === -1
~-2 === 1
~undefined === -1
~null === -1
~NaN === -1
```

Probably not ideal that it's trying to do the `splice` with some of those. For instance, the `true` will make it do a splice using index `1`, the `false` will be index `0`.

Comment: `~undefined`, `~null`, `~NaN`, and `~{}` all produce `-1` in Chrome 28 console.

Comment: thanks man you always helping the community...

Comment: @NoahFreitas: What was I thinking? And here I tested several, but they were the non-`NaN` ones. *sigh*