# What is the purpose of using ~ in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, zepto

I am trying to read the source code of `Zepto.js`. And there is a place in function `matches` that I don't understand:

```
zepto.matches = function(element, selector) {
    if (!selector || !element || element.nodeType !== 1) return false
    var matchesSelector = element.webkitMatchesSelector || element.mozMatchesSelector ||
                          element.oMatchesSelector || element.matchesSelector
    if (matchesSelector) return matchesSelector.call(element, selector)
    var match, parent = element.parentNode, temp = !parent
    if (temp) (parent = tempParent).appendChild(element)

    //Here is my question. This line used the `~`
    match = ~zepto.qsa(parent, selector).indexOf(element)
    temp && tempParent.removeChild(element)
    return match
}
```

Function `matches` is used for determines whether an element matches the selector provided. It should return a Boolean.

And the `zepto.qsa()` is Zepto's CSS selector implementation which uses `document.querySelectorAll` and some other optimizes.

So. What is the purpose of the `~` in the following code ?

```
match = ~zepto.qsa(parent, selector).indexOf(element)
```

I know that `~` means `Bitwise NOT`.

And (by my own tests):

`~ -1 === 0`

`~ 0 === -1`

`~ 1 === -2`

But I still don't understand what this design is for.

Can someone explain?

Comment: If you know it's a bitwise NOT, then what's the issue? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654057/where-would-i-use-a-bitwise-operator-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9316612/1331430

Comment: Ma Cheng, numbers can be booleans in javascript because it is dynamically typed. Zero is false and every other integer is equivalent to true. This function is using the way a bitwise NOT operates on the results of indexOf() and the truthiness of integers in javascript in order to work.

Comment: @MikeD. Thanks!  I realized now.  I was confused by it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is using the [bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) operator to invert the results of the [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function.

I'm not familiar with zepto.js but I can make a guess as to what the code is doing. First it calls the `zepto.qsa()` method and passes the parent object and the selector. This method must return an array because it then calls `indexOf()` to get the index for the element (which I assume is the element being "matched").

The `Array.indexOf()` method returns -1 if the element is not found in the collection. As you've already seen a bitwise NOT on -1 gives you zero, which is equivalent to `false`. [Any other value that could come out would be equivalent to `true`.](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

> More generally this means you can use a bitwise NOT on `indexOf()` to
>   get a boolean value indicating if the element searched for exists in
>   the collection or not.

Comment: Thanks. I realized now. I've just been using `~arr.indexOf( x ) == true` in my own tests. So I've got mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. it's a bitwise NOT, so you can use it when working with bits.

As for practical applications when you normally don't find yourself working with bits, here's a little trick:

```
 if (~arr.indexOf(val)) doStuff();

 //instead of

 if (arr.indexOf(val) > -1) doStuff();
```

--edit--

I realize I didn't see you ask for an explanation for using `~` with `indexOf`.  Simply put, `~-1` evaluates to `0`.  When you are using an if statement, `0` is a false value.  It's a shorthand way for writing `arr.indexOf(val) > -1`.