# Datatables remove this !!~ it doesnt return

Tags: jquery

Regarding in this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/oL2uum3L/4/)

I dont understand whats the use of this `!!~`

This is the script in fiddle

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
   function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var tdValues=[];
      var $tds=table.row(dataIndex).nodes().to$().find('td');
      $tds.each(function(){
         var $this=$(this);
         var hasSelect=$this.find('select').length >0; // check if current cell has a select box
         var curTdValue= hasSelect ? $this.find('option:selected').text() : $this.text();
         tdValues.push(curTdValue);
      });
      var rowValues=tdValues.join(' ');
      return !!~rowValues.toLowerCase().indexOf(table.search().toLowerCase()); //<---this area
   }     
);
```

If I remove the `!!~` It doesnt return. I cant see it in the manual of datatables about this also this `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push` I cant also see this in their manual.

EDITED

This answered the [tilde or ~](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316612/how-does-not-not-tilde-bang-bang-tilde-alter-the-result-of-a-contains-inc) but how about this? `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does !!~ (not not tilde/bang bang tilde) alter the result of a 'contains/included' Array method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316612/how-does-not-not-tilde-bang-bang-tilde-alter-the-result-of-a-contains-inc)

Comment: @CBroe I see thanks but how about this `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push` I didnt see it in their manual

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization check this jsfiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/jignesh221290/oL2uum3L/27/`

Comment: This is just an application of datatable’s mechanism for adding search plugins - https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search

Comment: @jigneshpatel thanks