# JQuery: What does this code mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(~$.inArray('orange', apple))
```

Can anyone explain what is the above code mean in jquery?

what is ~ and .inArray?

Comment: jQuery inArray http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FBitwise_Operators

Comment: @Kevin, more like showing off and killing readability, if you ask me.

Comment: @kevin, if you try it in a browser, you'll find that it flips between 0 and -1.  which is interpreted properly as falsey and truthy respectively

Comment: @Kevin, that's actually a side effect of two's complement: it will map `-1` to `0`, `0` to `-1` and positive numbers to non-zero numbers. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9316724/464709) for details.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question after all... The code is not intuitive.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191531/what-does-mean-in-javascript

Comment: @iJay it means "found in array", not found is `!~$.inArray()`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi i'm not sure comparing something to -1 is more readable than setting a sign before an evaluated expression. I mean do you find: `if($.inArray('orange', apple) !== -1)` more readable than just `if(~$.inArray('orange', apple))` but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means nothing in jQuery as it is JavaScript.

`~` is an operator that does something that you’d normally think wouldn’t have any purpose. It is a unary operator that takes the expression to its right performs this small algorithm on it (where N is the expression to the right of the tilde): -(N+1). See below for some samples.

```
console.log(~-2); // 1
console.log(~-1); // 0
console.log(~0);  // -1
console.log(~1);  // -2
console.log(~2);  // -3
```

So, unless you actually have an application that needs to run this algorithm on numbers

[Source Taken from](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/)

### inArray

> Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).

so in combination if element not find on `(~$.inArray('orange', apple))` it will return zero else index will be converted as above given series.